# Empathy is not connecting to gmail account on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, empathy, gmail

I have upgraded from 15.04 to 16.04 and Empathy communicator is not connecting to my gmail account. I have it set up correctly in my Network Accounts but the spinning weel keeps spinning and spinning and never goes online. Please help.
[image]

Comment: It is most likely that google has blocked the login from “unknown” sources. Can you check for the notification email from google from another device or different software?

Comment: No notifications unfortunately...